# Packaging javafx jar as application for mac

Tags: windows, macos, javafx

I've made a jar file that requires javafx libraries to run. I know that the command to run it is:
`java --module-path /PATH_TO_JAVAFX_SDK --add-modules javafx.controls -jar FILE.jar`. This is all well and good, but is there a way to package this into a Mac application and/or a Windows exe so that my users won't have to download the FX SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must make a fat JAR, i.e. a JAR file which contains all the dependencies your project requires. You can add libraries into your JAR by clicking the following in IntelliJ:

File > Project Structure > Artifacts > click the "+" symbol > Extracted Directory > and then select all the .jar files in the JavaFX folder.

If you're using JavaFX 11 or above, also include the .so files:

File > Project Structure > Artifacts > click the "+" symbol > File > and then select all the .so files in the JavaFX folder.

Comment: .so files? I'm not seeing any in the lib directory. Also when I try running it, I just get the error: ```JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application```